# does wso2 carbon 4.1 support feature provisioning where carbon sits behind a proxy?

Tags: wso2

I have run into issues installing features when carbon sits behind a proxy - see [JIRA ISSUE](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-14127).

Does wso2 carbon 4.1 support installing features via a proxy?

If it does support proxies for installing features, how is the proxy configured in wso2 carbon?

**EDIT: (8th June 2013)**

It seems that eclipse p2 which is used by wso2 for feature management does not support proxies using the standard java system properties: `-Dhttp.proxyHost` and `-Dhttp.proxyPort`.  See [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Hudson#Configuring_a_proxy_for_the_p2_director)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the lack of answers, I can only guess that the answer to this question is: **No, wso2 carbon 4.1 does NOT support feature provisioning where carbon sits behind a proxy?**